# My Rest Mappings not found when use @EnableAsync

Tags: java, spring-boot, asynchronous

I use spring-boot in micro service arch when i use @EnableAsync annotation in config like this

```
@Configuration
@EnableAsync
public class AsyncConfig implements AsyncConfigurer {
    @Bean("taskExecutor")
    public AsyncTaskExecutor taskExecutor() {
        final ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.setCorePoolSize(16);
        executor.setMaxPoolSize(1024 * 100);
        executor.setQueueCapacity(1024 * 1000);whay
        executor.setThreadNamePrefix("task-pool-");
        executor.initialize();
        return executor;
    }

}
```

my rest controllers won't detect anymore and get warn like this:

```
2022-08-01 10:32:03.086  WARN 1185196 --- [nio-1503-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound             : No mapping for GET /api/cycle/all/byYear
```

why?

Comment: Can you share the link to your code repository?

Comment: Did you add an @Async("taskExecutor") to the controller?